# Getting information on geo file projection in Python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, well-known-text

I have many geo files with different extensions, from different sources (mid/mif, shape, geojson, dat). I'd like to get information on their projection (i've no access to epsg code).

Maybe, I search for the equivalent of `ogrinfo` linux command in Python. I can't use the following code, because the final program has to be functional on Windows and Linux :

```
# Python code
args = ['ogrinfo', '-so', '-al', 'destination_data.shp']
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

The goal is to get srs/crs info as wkt (as the following result) in order to use the `http://prj2epsg.org/` api :

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```